# accessing local caches from docker

Tags: docker, offline-caching

Basically, I want to configure my laptop so I can (re)create docker images without a network connection.

Most package managers offer ways to download packages locally - that's easy. The trick appears to be making those caches available to the docker image without using networking and local servers for each type of package manager.

For a concrete example, consider the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazonlinux:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# get the tools we need
RUN yum install -y python27-devel python27-pip gcc openssl-devel zip findutils git
RUN pip install --disable-pip-version-check --upgrade pip setuptools

# Dev requirements
COPY requirements-dev.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements-dev.txt
```

I can populate local directories with the desired content, but would prefer not to re-invent the wheel about making them available to the docker image. Ideally, I could use a machine global cache, rather than per project caches.

Anyone willing to share a working solution? FWIW, I only need the solution to work on posix type systems.

Comment: What about using a Docker volume?

Comment: Yes, but has anyone worked out the mechanics? ;) 

All the related tools would need to be told where to place their cache so it fits into the needed volume. That sort of planning is not my long suit.